# apps script stuck in loop?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, onchange

My code was working, but then I changed around some columns and updated the script. Now the function seems to be stuck in a loop. Basically, my script should run once when a new row is added to a table. (I add the new row via an IFTTT trigger.) The below function is scheduled to trigger onchange()

```
function phototable() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('###').getSheetByName('IFTTT');
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var imageID = 'MID(C'+lastRow+',32,33)';
  var name = ss.getRange('G'+lastRow);
  var address = ss.getRange('H'+lastRow);
  var phone = ss.getRange('I'+lastRow);
  var email = ss.getRange('J'+lastRow);
  ss.getRange('D'+lastRow).setValue('=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://drive.google.com/file/d/"&'+imageID+'),'+imageID+')');    //ss.getRange('D'+lastRow).setFormula('MID(C'+lastRow+',32,33)');
  ss.getRange('E'+lastRow).setFormula('LEFT(B'+lastRow+',8)');
  name.setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###","Form Responses!R:AA"),7,false)');
  address.setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###","Form Responses!R:AA"),8,false)');
  phone.setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/184C3kCDDv2sCElQB-INIyzTvmx8oNDXF0xqO7AH7xs8","Form Responses!R:AA"),9,false)');
  email.setValue('=VLOOKUP("Form Responses_Images/"&B'+lastRow+',importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/###","Form Responses!R:AA"),10,false)');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  name.copyTo(name,{contentsOnly:true});
  address.copyTo(address,{contentsOnly:true});
  phone.copyTo(phone,{contentsOnly:true});
  email.copyTo(email,{contentsOnly:true});
  
  
 var key = ss.getRange('F'+lastRow);
  key.setValue('=DEC2HEX(RANDBETWEEN(0, 4294967295), 8)');    
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  key.copyTo(key,{contentsOnly:true});
  
  for(var row=lastRow;row>1;row--){
    if(ss.getRange('B'+row).isBlank()){
      ss.deleteRow(row);}
  }
  
}
```

The script runs and produces the correct values but it seems to be stuck in a never ending loop as it continually creates a new `key` and retrieves values for columns G:J.

Here's my table:
[image]

Any ideas? I tried the onedit() trigger instead but that doesn't actually trigger the function.

Here is my executions page:
[image]

Comment: The script is only called once for each row inserted by IFTTT. I don't know where the script executions page is. The last row is the row that IFTTT adds and IFTTT populates columns A:C. Columns D:E are formulas. And columns F:J are done via the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It migth be possible that `ss.deleteRow(row)` is triggering your on change trigger. Another possible situation is that IFTTT is triggering multiple times the on on change trigger. In any case try the following:

replace

```
function phototable(){
```

by

```
function phototable(e){
  if(e.changeType !== 'INSERT_ROW') return;
```

The above will make that rest of the code will only be executed when a new row is inserted.

The side effect is that you will not be able to execute the function directly but you can use the following

```
function test_phototable(){
  var e = {changeType:'INSERT_ROW'};
  phototable(e);
}
```

Comment: It's not the delete row that's causing the loop. When I comment out 
`````
    `for(var row=lastRow;row>1;row--){
        if(ss.getRange('B'+row).isBlank()){
          ss.deleteRow(row);}
      }`
`````````
the looping still occurs.

Comment: It's very strange. It looks to be working but the executions page shows that the script is still running?

Comment: The executions page is a bit "buggy". Try refreshing the corresponding web browswer tab.

Comment: @testing123 Yay! I'm glad that it's finally working :)